# Need help taking coordinates from user and locating a letter on matrix from file

Tags: c

I have have an assignment for my coding class where we have to first open up a user inputted file that contains a matrix of letters:

Ex.

```
SSSS
BBSS
SSSS
```

then the user inputs coordinates and depending on what letter the coordinate is, they win or lose the game.

I have a code to open the file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000   

int main (void) { 

  FILE* input = NULL;
  char a[MAX] = ""; 

  printf("Enter a filename: ");
  fscanf (stdin, " %1023[^\n]", a);

  if ((input = fopen (a, "r")) == NULL) {
      perror ("fopen-a");
      return 1;
  }
}
```

How can I now take user inputted coordinates and correspond them to a letter on the matrix within the file?

Comment: Take a step back and describe more precisely where you are stuck.  How are the co-ordinates to be represented?  Are they integer values?  What does the input look like for that?  Do you know how to read co-ordinates?  Do you know how to read lines of text from a file?  Do you know how to store data in an array?  Do you even need to do that, or do you plan to simply parse the file and calculate co-ordinates on-the-fly?  As a beginner, you will benefit from itemizing all the small things your program needs to do, and just focus on one small task at a time.

Comment: So the coordinates are entered as such: 0 0. These would correspond to the top left most corner of the array. I've able to create a code that takes an array inputted by the user and saves each input as "arr[i][j]" where i is the row and j is the column. From there I can just use simple if statements to complete the task. However, my problem now is that I don't know how to take a pre-made array/matrix and apply the same knowledge where an i/j value is assigned to each character. I am very new to coding (if you couldn't tell) so I hope this made sense.

Comment: An array input by the user is the same as an array input by a file.  There is basically no difference between reading data from the console or from a file.  See, you're _already_ using `stdin` explicitly.  The type of `stdin` is `FILE*`.  If you want to read data from your file, use `input` (the name of your open file handle) instead of `stdin`.

Comment: In the code I made it takes the users input 1 character at a time. So the code already knows the coordinates of each character, then it asks the user for coordinates and can simply use an 'if' statement to determine if the user wins or loses. However, with a file input the character array is read all at once and each character is not already assigned a coordinate. Is there a way to assign each one a specific coordinate? or am I going about this all wrong? Thanks so much for the help btw

Comment: What do you mean?  The array is not being read from the file _at all_, according to the code you've shown.  You opened a file, and then your program exits.  If you have read this data from the file, show the code that does it.  It might be unnecessary to "read an array all at once" from your file.  Your problem could be solved in several ways.  One easy way is to read one character at a time until you hit end of file or locate the co-ordinate you're searching for.  Each character advances the column, unless it's a newline which resets the column and advances the row.

Comment: How would I go about reading one character at a time? And if I did this, would the code know that say 0 0 is an 'S'?

Comment: There is no need to ask the same question twice.

Comment: I just described how you can _count_ co-ordinates as you read characters from the file.  You would read the _target_ co-ordinate from the user like you presumably already do.  The function `fgetc` will read a single character.  You then apply the logic that I provided above.  I'm not going to provide any more comments here.  If you're still stuck, then go back and read my very first comment.